# Running into "This code should have never made it into the jar" error

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I have an application created which makes use of Hikari CP, and a user of this application is running into this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268) ~[?:?]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241) ~[?:?]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254) ~[?:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig.<clinit>(AbstractHikariConfig.java:43) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This code should have never made it into the jar
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:63) ~[?:?]
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:44) ~[?:?]
```

I have not included any code as I am unsure of what code would be relevant to this, and the issue is that this error is being ran into by a user of the application, I am unable to replicate the issue on my end as it works perfectly for me and a few others and as a result I am unsure of what may be causing it for this specific user. It appears to be occurring when I create a SQLite connection using HikariCP.

The jar is created using Maven and the relevant dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post what's at `AbstractHikariConfig.java` line 43? But this looks like a bug of `slf4j`?

Comment: @Tunaki that's part of https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP. It might be a bug of slf4j, I came here with the question since I couldn't figure out why it was only one out of around 12-13 users that are running into this issue which is why I am curious as to what could be causing it.

Comment: I don't see any AbstractHikaryConfig in [the project you mentioned](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/tree/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari).

Comment: @Tunaki sorry, here is the correct link for it's source http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.3.0/com/zaxxer/hikari/AbstractHikariConfig.java

Comment: You should always use fixed versions in a pom.xml. Different users can end up with different versions of that dependency (if they build the application themselves or consume them in their own project). Additionally, with slf4j 1.7.13, the StaticLoggerBinder is no longer in the api JAR, so if you use that version, that error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

From the SLF4J [website](http://www.slf4j.org):

> Note that SLF4J-enabling your library implies the addition of only a single mandatory dependency, namely slf4j-api.jar. If no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation.

I assume because both classes have the same name (StaticLoggerBinder), the api version was shaded first.

To solve it, try placing the `slf4j-simple` dependency above the `slf4j-api` dependency.

Comment: Are you shading? If so, can you decompile and see which `StaticLoggerBinder` was shaded? If not, can you please post your classpath?

Comment: Just checked, appears to be the `StaticLoggerBinder` of `slf4j-simple`

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what could be wrong. Hopefully someone else can help you out